# How to group query with multiple $cond?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to query like below, but this contains only one `$cond`.

How to query with two `$cond`?

```
collection.aggregate(
    { 
        $match : { 
            '_id' : {$in:ids}
        } 
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$someField',
            ...
            count: {$sum: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$otherField", false] } , 1, 0 ] }}
        }
    },
    function(err, result){
        ...
    }
);
```

Comment: If they are quite different then you will need to add a whole new field to the `$group` which is basically a copy of your `count` field but named differently of course

Comment: I want to check $anotherField, "value" and $otherField, false

Comment: But I assume you also want documents that do not satisfy that clause otherwise you could have put it into the match

Comment: yes I want to get other documents that not satisfying that clause. So the conditions must be in sum clause ..

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what you want to do, but there are a few other examples on StackOverflow of either [nested `$cond`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19967701) (similar to a case statement) or use of [multiple `$cond`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20620879). I think what you are after is a nested `$cond`, where you conditionally sum matches for `$anotherField` by adding another `$cond` comparison in the expression where `$otherField` is not false.

Comment: @Stennie it would be awesome to document the use of $and there in the first link, I was gonna try that when I had a chance but since it isn't documented I had no idea if it would work

Comment: you mean like here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#boolean-operators ?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky yeah like that...not sure why I didn't see that

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You want to use a compound expression inside `{$cond:[]}` - something like:

```
collection.aggregate(
    { 
        $match : { 
            '_id' : {$in:ids}
        } 
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$someField',
            ...
            count: {$sum: { $cond: [ {$and : [ { $eq: [ "$otherField", false] },
                                               { $eq: [ "$anotherField","value"] }
                                     ] },
                                     1,
                                     0 ] }}
        }
    },
    function(err, result){
        ...
    }
);
```

The [`$and` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/and/#exp._S_and) is documented here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#boolean-operators

Comment: Can we use function() in an aggregation pipeline ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean but within the pipeline everything has to resolve into pipeline syntax, in other words you can use a function to expand something into proper syntax but not to have it called at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

you can add multiple $cond and multiple criterias inside $cond like this
`

```
collection.aggregate(
[
  {
    "$match": {
      //matching criteria
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "service": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            "$eq": [
              "$foo",
              "bar"
            ]
          },
          "then": "return string1",
          "else": {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                "$eq": [
                  "$foo",
                  "bar"
                ]
              },
              "then": "return string2",
              "else": {
                "$cond": {
                  "if": {
                    "$or": [
                      {
                        "$eq": [
                          "$foo",
                          "bar1"
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "$eq": [
                          "$foo",
                          "bar2"
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  "then": "return string3",
                  "else": "$foo"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "_id": 0
    }
  }
]
)
```

`