# How to get multiple conditional sum results on multiple nested arrays with single query in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, count

I need to get 2 sum results from 2 seperated nested arrays if contains some value, for 10 times (lets say product sum data for 10 countries). I know i need to use aggregate function but i dont figure it out.

I tried $facet but it tooks approximately 30-40 secs in 4.5 million document (with nested array data) to get result. ( Imagine that i need a loop for 10 times for this )

I tried following solutions but failed:

[How to group query with multiple $cond?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20836978/how-to-group-query-with-multiple-cond)

[Multiple Counts with single query in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52088666/multiple-counts-with-single-query-in-mongodb)

**collection structure:**

```
{
   _id,
   sku: 'p1',
   someField,
   someField2,
   ...
   products: [
    {
    productid:132,
      someproductfield,
      someproductfield2,
      ...
      countryId: double  <- The field which is used when sum conditon         
    },
    {
     productid:451,
      someproductfield,
      someproductfield2,
      ...
      countryId: double  <- The field which is used when sum conditon         
    },
     {
     productid:218,
      someproductfield,
      someproductfield2,
      ...
      countryId: double  <- The field which is used when sum conditon         
    }
   ],
   sellers: [
    {
      sellerid: 101001,
      somesellerfield,
      somesellerfield2,
      ...
      countryId: double  <- The field which is used when sum conditon 
    },
    {
      sellerid: 104201,
      somesellerfield,
      somesellerfield2,
      ...
      countryId: double  <- The field which is used when sum conditon 
    },
{
      sellerid: 205401,
      somesellerfield,
      somesellerfield2,
      ...
      countryId: double  <- The field which is used when sum conditon 
    }
   ]
},
{
   _id,
   sku: 'x2',
   someField,
   someField2,
   ...
   products: [
    {
    productid:142,
      someproductfield,
      someproductfield2,
      ...
      countryId: double  <- The field which is used when sum conditon         
    },
    {
     productid:71,
      someproductfield,
      someproductfield2,
      ...
      countryId: double  <- The field which is used when sum conditon         
    },
     {
     productid:28,
      someproductfield,
      someproductfield2,
      ...
      countryId: double  <- The field which is used when sum conditon         
    }
   ],
   sellers: [
    {
      sellerid: 1001,
      somesellerfield,
      somesellerfield2,
      ...
      countryId: double  <- The field which is used when sum conditon 
    },
    {
      sellerid: 1421,
      somesellerfield,
      somesellerfield2,
      ...
      countryId: double  <- The field which is used when sum conditon 
    },
{
      sellerid: 20501,
      somesellerfield,
      somesellerfield2,
      ...
      countryId: double  <- The field which is used when sum conditon 
    }
   ]
},
{
   _id,
   sku: 'p3',
   someField,
   someField2,
   ...
   products: [
    {
    productid:543,
      someproductfield,
      someproductfield2,
      ...
      countryId: double  <- The field which is used when sum conditon         
    },
    {
     productid:52,
      someproductfield,
      someproductfield2,
      ...
      countryId: double  <- The field which is used when sum conditon         
    },
     {
     productid:32,
      someproductfield,
      someproductfield2,
      ...
      countryId: double  <- The field which is used when sum conditon         
    }
    ...
   ],
   sellers: [
    {
      sellerid: 5201,
      somesellerfield,
      somesellerfield2,
      ...
      countryId: double  <- The field which is used when sum conditon 
    },
    {
      sellerid: 1231,
      somesellerfield,
      somesellerfield2,
      ...
      countryId: double  <- The field which is used when sum conditon 
    },
{
      sellerid: 12565461,
      somesellerfield,
      somesellerfield2,
      ...
      countryId: double  <- The field which is used when sum conditon 
    }
   ]
}
```

i need the result like:

```
{
 countryId:5,
 productsOnCountryCount: 10102,    

/* something like count only products which has the countryId => 
$sum: { $cond: [{$eq: ['$products.countryId',2]},1,0] }
 */
 unavailableProductsCount: 3560
/* something like sellers have but not available to sell or list for some 
reason => 
$sum: {$cond: [{$and:[{$eq: ['$sellers.countryId',2]},{$ne: 
['$products.countryId',2]}]},1,0]}
*/
}
```

**UPDATE FOR APPROACHES AND RESPOND TIMES**

```
var cid = 2; // assume countryId of USA
target document total = about 20 million data (including nested arrays)
```

> Approach 1 (@KevinSmith) Response time : 48-50 sec

```
db.test.aggregate([
  { "$facet": {
    "productsOnCountryCount": [
      { "$unwind" : "$products" },
      { "$match" : { "products.countryId": cid}},
      { "$count": "productsOnCountryCount" },
    ],
    "unavailableProductsCount": [
      { "$match" : {"sellers.countryId": cid, "products.countryId" : { $ne: cid } } },
      { "$count": "unavailableProductsCount" }
    ]
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "productsOnCountryCount": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$productsOnCountryCount.productsOnCountryCount", 0] },
    "unavailableProductsCount": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$unavailableProductsCount.unavailableProductsCount", 0] }
  }}
]);
```

> Approach 2 Response time : 36-38 sec

```
db.test.aggregate([
        { "$facet": {          
          "count1": [
            { "$match" : {'products.countryId': cid }},
            { "$count": "Count" }
          ],
          "count2": [
            { "$match" : {'sellers.countryId': cid,'products.countryId':{$ne: cid} }},
            { "$count": "Count" }
          ]
        }}
      ])
```

> Approach 3 Response time : 20-21 sec

```
db.test.aggregate([
 {$group: {
        _id: null,
        distct: { $sum: { $cond: [{$in: [cid,'$products.countryId']},1,0] }},
         undistct: {
            $sum: { 
                $cond: [
                {$and: 
                    [
                    {$in: [cid,'$sellers.countryId']},
                    {$not:{$in: [cid,'$products.countryId']}}
                    ]},
                    1,
                    0
                    ] }}
     }
 }
])
```

According to the results i think im gonna choose approach 3.
Thanks to everyone interested

Comment: Can you provide a small collection sample and the output of the aggregation what you require as I'm not sure what you want to sum on what conditions.

Comment: @KevinSmith i already mentioned it  in the **ineed the result like** section. And i typed the query what i want with conditions. Issue is how to combine all of these with optimal single query.

Comment: assume cid=3 => the country id for query. All i want is result of combine of **$sum: { $cond: [{$eq: ['$products.countryId',cid]},1,0] }**  and   **$sum: {$cond: [{$and:[{$eq: ['$sellers.countryId',cid]},{$ne: ['$products.countryId',cid]}]},1,0]}**

Comment: What indexes do you have?

Answer (score 2):

So let's start off by simplifiying the dataset, we'll insert a list of items in to our `test` collection:

```
var items = [{
  _id : 1,
  products: [
    {
      countryId: 1 
    },
    {
      countryId: 1
    },
    {
      countryId: 2
    },
    {
      countryId: 4
    },
  ],
  sellers: [
    {
      countryId: 2
    },
    {
      countryId: 2
    },
    {
      countryId: 1
    }
  ]  
},
{
  _id : 2,
  products: [
  {
    countryId: 2
  },
  {
    countryId: 2
  },
  {
    countryId: 3
  }
  ],
  sellers: [
  {
    countryId: 3
  },
  {
    countryId: 3
  },
  {
    countryId: 2
  },
  {
    countryId: 4
  }
  ]
}];

db.test.insertMany(items);
```

We then can use the `$facet` aggregation stage to process multiple aggregation pipelines, so let's start by just using working out the pipeline for `productsOnCountryCount`.

To start with we need to unwind all the `products` in the array and then match then based on a given countryId:

```
var countryId = 4;

db.test.aggregate([
  { "$unwind" : "$products" },
  { "$match" : { "products.countryId": countryId } }
]).pretty()
{
        "_id" : 1,
        "products" : {
                "countryId" : 4
        },
        "sellers" : [
                {
                        "countryId" : 2
                },
                {
                        "countryId" : 2
                },
                {
                        "countryId" : 1
                }
        ]
}
```

We can now just use a count on the end to get the count of all the products:

```
db.test.aggregate([
  { "$unwind" : "$products" },
  { "$match" : { "products.countryId": countryId}},
  { "$count": "productsOnCountryCount" }])
{ "productsOnCountryCount" : 1 }
```

That's our first pipeline sorted now let's take a look at `unavailableProductsCount`:

All we need to do is match where the countryId is in the `sellers` array but not in the `products` array, this can be achived with a simple `$match` stage, then we can just run a count over the top:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    { "$match" : {"sellers.countryId": countryId, "products.countryId" : { $ne: countryId } } },
    { "$count": "unavailableProductsCount" }])
{ "unavailableProductsCount" : 1 }
```

Now we have our two pipelines we can now use the `$facet` stage to join them together and then project them in to a nicer form:

```
db.test.aggregate([
  { "$facet": {
    "productsOnCountryCount": [
      { "$unwind" : "$products" },
      { "$match" : { "products.countryId": countryId}},
      { "$count": "productsOnCountryCount" },
    ],
    "unavailableProductsCount": [
      { "$match" : {"sellers.countryId": countryId, "products.countryId" : { $ne: countryId } } },
      { "$count": "unavailableProductsCount" }
    ]
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "productsOnCountryCount": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$productsOnCountryCount.productsOnCountryCount", 0] },
    "unavailableProductsCount": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$unavailableProductsCount.unavailableProductsCount", 0] }
  }}
]);

{ "productsOnCountryCount" : 1, "unavailableProductsCount" : 1 }
```

I find the best way to use `$facet` is just to break them down in to smaller pipelines first and then join them together at the end.

Comment: thanks for your awesome explain. I tried your $facet solution but it took about 48 sec. I'll update my question for response times.

Comment: @harun do you have an index on `products.countryId` / `sellers.countryId`?

Comment: Sure i have products.cuntryId and sellers.countryId indexes together and each of them separated.

Comment: All I can suggest is doing an explain and see what it's doing?